# How do i resolve flutter objectbox build error?

Tags: flutter, objectbox

I'm a Flutter developer
I'm using the obejctbox package for saving local DB.

When i upgrade flutter version and build app to make objectbox.g.dart by "flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs" command, app show erorr like below

Invalid argument(s): name shouldn't end with a '.'

I also create another flutter project and build_runner command works well.

How can i resolve this "Invalid argument(s): name shouldn't end with a '.'"  error?

Stackoverflow
ChatGPT4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your pubspeck.lock you have the `logging` dependency? I was facing the same issue in build_runner and it seems that has a kind of bug with the recent version of logging. As a workaround I set the logging version to "1.1.0" and it works.

Here is the issue: https://github.com/dart-lang/build/issues/3447